# In Solidity, what are the differences in purpose between overriding isApprovedForAll() and enabling meta-transactions?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, polygon, opensea, meta-transactions

When setting up an OpenSea-compatible contract in Solidity for the Polygon network, what are the differences in purpose between overriding `isApprovedForAll()` and enabling meta-transactions?

From looking over [the documentation](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/polygon-basic-integration), it appears that hard-coding OpenSea's proxy address in `isApprovedForAll()` saves both the contract owner and any eventual seller from having to later call `setApprovalForAll()`.

And, if I'm understanding this correctly, once OpenSea has been approved, it can transfer tokens from the seller to the buyer. It appears that OpenSea would be paying the gas for the transfer. Is that correct?

If so, this sounds like it is accomplishing what OpenSea says is the purpose for  meta-transactions: "Your smart contracts should support meta-transactions so that OpenSea can abstract away gas payments for users for methods such as transfers and sales."

Perhaps I've missed something here. Is there a difference in purpose between overriding `isApprovedForAll()` and enabling meta-transactions?

Answer (score 0):

OpenSea gave me this answer to the question:

> As a quick disclaimer, I am not a developer, but I can hopefully help
> to clarify a bit more on this.
>
> Generally, the 'isApprovedForAll' refers to Token Approvals, but by
> overriding this, it allows for OpenSea's smart contract to operate on
> your smart contract (which will save you and your buyers gas when
> selling and transferring tokens for the first time), whereas enabling
> meta-transactions allows for gass-less transactions beyond that. With
> that said, you are correct, but there is a slight difference, as token
> approvals are for the first interaction, but enabling metatransactions
> will allow us to pay for the gas for your buyers when your NFTs are
> transferred/sold in the future.